# Why do some of my unwrapped objects appear to have no UV data?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

I am making a trailer truck and I have more than 70 objects within my scene with correct uv mapping and texturing, while I was in Substance Painter I noticed that 2 of my objects were not working correctly as shown in this image:

[image]

There is no UV information on the right panel on neither of these objects, so I came back to Blender and this is what I found:

[image]

The door and the door part that holds the mirror aren't showing the UV checker squares, but the problem is that all the UVs are "fine".

[image]

The first thing I tried was looking into texture view to see if the textures were applied to my object and I saw this:

[image]

As you can see in texture view the UV checker squares are there, but as soon I look at it in render view mode this shows:

[image]

There you have also my node setup that isn't something very complicated, I really don't know what the problem is and why only those two objects are not working, if you have any advice on it I'll be pleased.

Comment: Just one material called doors, applied to both doors and it's nodes are on the last screenshot

Comment: Omg i finally found what was going on, when i was checking the custom split normals nothing happened, but then i saw the "uv map" tab, and i had 7 UV different maps and it was only rendering the first one, so i deleted all the previous maps and now it's finally working, thanks so much!

Comment: Glad you found the reason. You can go ahead and write an answer below with some details what you did to make it working